# how to change only the language of dashboard

Tags: dashboard, language

How can I change the language of just WordPress dashboard, so that the language of site still did not change? a lot of plugins and themes dashboard  becomes mess when I change it to my language, because it's RTL but plugins and themes are just LTR. I don't speak English very well, so sorry for my language.

Answer (score -3):

You should open your wp-config file in the root folder and edit this line.

define ('WPLANG', 'en_EN');

Please also check the following link: 
https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/set-up-wordpress-in-your-language/

Comment: No, that constant is obsolete.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it to you very well. You didn't understand it, I mean WordPress already have my language and I can choose my language in Settings/General, but when I change WordPress language to my language, everything including WordPress dashboard and all site becomes RTL, I don't want it, you know, my dashboard must be English and LTR, but my site must be persian and RTL. I think there is no way to do it, but if you know any way, please tell it to me, thanks

Comment: thanks toscho, it's duplicate and has been asked before, the best plugin for it that has not been obsolete, is English WordPress Admin